# Add additional Elements to xml structure using python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to take a single record out of an xml format, and multiply it such that each new instance will contain a different value of a certain fields.

I thought that the best way to do so is by preparing a skeleton xml file (see below) that contain a single instance (dummy instance). Then, my script will point this instance and for each loop iteration, it will substitute it's fields with the desired values, and append it back to the xml tree.

### xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServerData>
<CreationDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreationDate>
<Processes>
   <ProtectedProcess>
       <Name>XXX</Name>
       <Path>XXX</Path>
   </ProtectedProcess>
 </Processes>
</ServerData>
```

### my code :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
self.tree = ET.parse(infile)
self.root = self.tree.getroot()

processes    = self.root.find("Processes")    
process_root = self.root.find("Processes").find("ProtectedProcess")

for app in self.apps:
    process_root.find("Name").text = app.lower()
    process_root.find("Path",ns).text = app
    processes.append(process_root)

fd = open("./xxx.xml", "wb")
self.tree.write(fd, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=False)
```

Unfortunately, what i get is that in all the appended instances have the same value, according to the last iteration.

### xxx.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServerData>
<CreationDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreationDate>
<Processes>
   <ProtectedProcess>
       <Name>/applications/safari.app/contents/macos/safari</Name>
       <Path>/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari</Path>
   </ProtectedProcess>
   <ProtectedProcess>
       <Name>/applications/safari.app/contents/macos/safari</Name>
       <Path>/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari</Path>
   </ProtectedProcess>
   <ProtectedProcess>
       <Name>/applications/safari.app/contents/macos/safari</Name>
       <Path>/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari</Path>
   </ProtectedProcess>
 </Processes>
</ServerData>
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I've realized that I just duplicated the same instance over and over again (So when I set the fields in one of the instances, it applied to all duplications).

To get instances copies rather then duplications, I've used copy.deepcopy() method, as it can be shown in the following code snippet:

```
for app in self.apps:
    l=copy.deepcopy(process_root)
    l.find("d3p1:Name",ns).text = lower.app
    l.find("d3p1:Path",ns).text = app
    processes.append(l)
```